# Topology, Proving Interior and Exterior in $Q^n$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

We have the subsets $\mathbb Q$ (Rationals), $I=\mathbb R -\  \mathbb Q$ (Irrationals), and I want to prove that $(\mathbb Q)°=(I)°=Ø $and also find $Ext \mathbb Q $.

In order to prove that both subsets’ interior are empty, I proposed $x∈\mathbb Q$ such that for an $r > 0, B(x,r) ⊂ \mathbb Q,$ but $I=\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ are dense, such as $\mathbb Q,$ thus $B(x,r) ⊄ \mathbb Q $ and $x $ is never an interior point of $Q,$ we can’t find a complete ball inside $Q,$ which means that $(\mathbb Q)°=(I)°=Ø $(following the same steps for I).

Then, to find $Ext Q$, I defined $E=\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ and proposed y∈E and tried to fit a ball inside it so it could prove the existence of E by finding its interior. So, for an $r > 0, B(y,r) ⊂ E$, but $E=I$ and we already know that $(I)°=Ø$, thus $Ext \mathbb Q = Ø $(same for $Ext I$).

But then I’m asked to find $(\mathbb Q^n)°$ and$ Ext (\mathbb Q^n)$, if $\mathbb Q^n = \{x∈R^n | x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), x_i ∈ \mathbb Q, 0\leq x \leq 1\},$ could I use the same method? Is my proof for the first two paragraphs correct and sufficient? Thanks

Comment: When you say "We have the subsets Q, I=R\Q", do you refer to the rational and irrational numbers as subsets of the real numbers?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: It's more common to use $\mathbb{P}$ for the irrationals, $I$ suggests an interval to me.

Answer (score 1):

Fact of life: every open ball contains rational and irrational points.
This implies all of the following, straight from the definitions:

- $\mathbb{Q}^\circ = \emptyset$.
- $\mathbb{P}^\circ  =\emptyset$.
- $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$.
- $\overline{\mathbb{P}} = \mathbb{R}$.

So $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \emptyset$ and similarly for the irrationals $\mathbb{P}$.